# Why is this simple Z3 proof so slow?

Tags: z3

The following Z3 code times out on the online repl:

```
; I want a function
(declare-fun f (Int) Int)

; I want it to be linear
(assert (forall ((a Int) (b Int)) (
  = (+ (f a) (f b)) (f (+ a b))
)))

; I want f(2) == 4
(assert (= (f 2) 4))

; TIMEOUT :(
(check-sat)
```

So does this version, where it is looking for a function on the reals:

```
(declare-fun f (Real) Real)
(assert (forall ((a Real) (b Real)) (
  = (+ (f a) (f b)) (f (+ a b))
)))
(assert (= (f 2) 4))
(check-sat)
```

It's faster when I give it a contradiction:

```
(declare-fun f (Real) Real)
(assert (forall ((a Real) (b Real)) (
  = (+ (f a) (f b)) (f (+ a b))
)))
(assert (= (f 2) 4))
(assert (= (f 4) 7))
(check-sat)
```

I'm quite unknowledgeable about theorem provers. What is so slow here? Is the prover just having lots of trouble proving that linear functions with f(2) = 4 exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The slowness is most likely due to too many quantifier instantiations, caused by problematic *patterns*/*triggers*. If you don't know about these yet, have a look at the corresponding section of the [Z3 guide](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/tutorial/guide).

Bottom line: patterns are a syntactic heuristic, indicating to the SMT solver when to instantiate the quantifier. Patterns must cover all quantified variables and interpreted functions such as addition (`+`) are not allowed in patterns. A *matching loop* is a situation in which every quantifier instantiation gives rise to further quantifier instantiations.

In your case, Z3 probably picks the pattern set `:pattern ((f a) (f b))` (since you don't explicitly provide patterns). This suggests Z3 to instantiate the quantifier for every `a, b` for which the ground terms `(f a)` and `(f b)` have already occurred in the current proof search. Initially, the proof search contains `(f 2)`; hence, the quantifier can be instantiated with `a, b` bound to `2, 2`. This yields `(f (+ 2 2))`, which can be used to instantiate the quantifier once more (and also in combination with `(f 2)`). Z3 is thus stuck in a matching loop.

Here is a snippet arguing my point:

```
(set-option :smt.qi.profile true)

(declare-fun f (Int) Int)

(declare-fun T (Int Int) Bool) ; A dummy trigger function

(assert (forall ((a Int) (b Int)) (! 
  (= (+ (f a) (f b)) (f (+ a b)))
  :pattern ((f a) (f b))
  ; :pattern ((T a b))
)))

(assert (= (f 2) 4))

(set-option :timeout 5000) ; 5s is enough
(check-sat)
(get-info :reason-unknown)
(get-info :all-statistics)
```

With the explicitly provided pattern you'll get your original behaviour (modulo the specified timeout). Moreover, the statistics report lots of instantiations of the quantifier (and more still if you increase the timeout).

If you comment the first pattern and uncomment the second, i.e. if you "guard" the quantifier with a dummy trigger that won't show up in the proof search, then Z3 terminates immediately. Z3 will still report `unknown`, though, because it "knowns" that it did not account for the quantified constraint (which would be a requirement for `sat`; and it also cannot show `unsat`).

It is sometimes possible to rewrite quantifiers in order to have better triggering behaviour. The Z3 guide, for example, illustrates that in the context of injective functions/inverse functions. Maybe you'll be able to perform a similar transformation here.

Comment: Hey I'm wondering if there are some other options that changed because while what you're saying makes sense, even with the second pattern, for me Z3 is taking the full 5 seconds to terminate. Although like you said, the number of instantiations are much lower.